# Wrapping Margin Notes

Tags: lists, margins, marginpar, wrapfigure, wrap

I'm writing a small list of things and want to insert a small kind of box into the margin on right side of the list.

I'd like it to behave more or less like this:
If it fits into the margin fine.
If not, occupy some space for normal text, while still sitting mainly in the margin
If not, wrap into the (list) text (as far as i could gather this is the crux)
Or look for a place where there are short list items, since theres alot of wasted space there

Does there exist some kind of solution for this?
`\marginpar` only uses the margin which is too little space
`\wrapfigure` does exactly what I want, but won't work at all for lists (i can't even force the position, it just sits where it wants no matter what I enforce)

Due to my limited knowledge, the only thing I can think of that could be possible is somehow placing a minipage at a specified position on the page and then manually making sure that nothing overlaps, but I don't know how to do that, or if that works

Comment: What is the purpose of your lists? Will they be deleted in the final version of your text or are you looking for an automatic two-column layout? So please give an explanation and maybe an example which demonstrates the practical use of the desired lists.